# Error in constructor: couldn't execute "git": no such file or directory

Tags: perl, git, tcl, irc, bots

Ok, so I am setting up a modified eggdrop bot, but after getting all the required perl modules and libraries, I am getting this error:

```
sudo perl run-test
Running bot 18076
tcltest

Error in constructor: couldn't execute "git": no such file or directory at tcltest.pl line 12.
```

Here is line 12 of tcltest.pl:

```
print $tcl->EvalFile("smeggdrop.tcl"),$/;
```

Which contains:

```
# smeggdrop.tcl
encoding system utf-8
set SMEGGDROP_ROOT [file dirname [info script]]

if [file exists smeggdrop.conf] {source smeggdrop.conf}
source $SMEGGDROP_ROOT/smeggdrop/smeggdrop.tcl
```

And smeggdrop.conf is:

```
# smeggdrop.conf
#
# HTTP limits
#
set smeggdrop_http_requests_per_eval  5                     ;# Maximum number of requests per eval per channel
set smeggdrop_http_request_interval   60                    ;# Interval for the smeggdrop_http_request_limit setting, in seconds
set smeggdrop_http_request_limit      25                    ;# Maximum number of requests per interval per channel
set smeggdrop_http_post_limit         150000                ;# Maximum POST body size
set smeggdrop_http_transfer_limit     150000                ;# Maximum GET response size
set smeggdrop_http_time_limit         5000                  ;# Maximum execution time, in milliseconds
set smeggdrop_log_max_lines           20                    ;# Maximum lines to record per channel

#
# Publish settings - comment these out if you don't want [publish]
#
# set smeggdrop_publish_url             http://www.example.org/           ;# URL to publish to
# set smeggdrop_publish_hostname        example.org                       ;# SSH hostname
# set smeggdrop_publish_username        myusername                        ;# SSH username
# set smeggdrop_publish_password        mypassword                        ;# SSH password
# set smeggdrop_publish_filename        /home/example/htdocs/index.txt    ;# Filename to write to
```

Comment: The obvious question: is git installed? Where? Is it in the PATH when you run the script?

Comment: git is installed.  How do I add it to PATH?

Comment: That script! It sets `encoding system`! That's *so* going to blow up in a messy way if someone has it installed on a non-UTF8 system in a directory with a non-ASCII char in the name (or subdir of it). Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `source smeggdrop/smeggdrop.tcl`: [`smeggdrop.tcl`](https://github.com/shaniqua/smeggdrop/blob/master/smeggdrop/smeggdrop.tcl), in turns, sources [`smeggdrop/versioned_interpreter.tcl`](https://github.com/shaniqua/smeggdrop/blob/master/smeggdrop/versioned_interpreter.tcl) which has a section like:

```
  method initialize_repository {} {
    mkdir_p [$self path]
    mkdir_p [$self path procs]
    mkdir_p [$self path vars]
    touch [$self path procs _index]
    touch [$self path vars _index]

    if ![$self repository_exists] {
      $self git init
      $self git add procs vars
      $self commit "Created repository"
    }
  }
```

That means git has to be in the `PATH` to be found by this perl script.

Modify the **[path in the right `rc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works)** (depending on your default shell), [adding the git `bin` directory,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550490/how-can-i-put-home-opt-git-bin-to-my-path) and you won't have this issue anymore.